# Mid-2010 MacBook Pro - HP ZR30W - mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort?

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport

I am trying to get my new HP ZR30W working at full 2560x1600 with my mid-2010 MacBook Pro through a mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable.

I have seen people saying they have it working, but I can't seem to get it to accept anything but the 1280x800 res, even with SwitchResX.

I know the current Mac solution is a $100 mini DisplayPort to dual-link DVI adapter, but that seems rediculous to me when the monitor has a DisplayPort input.

Anyone have this working and have tips?

Update: I gave up after much tinkering and bought the adapter. I would still love to hear if anyone has made this work.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you just have a defective unit. There's no active circuitry in a mini-Displayport to Displayport connector, and a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=zr30w+mac+displayport) suggests that this monitor has worked with Macs over Displayport (as you would expect), but some people have had resolution detection issues.

If the dual-link adapter is working for you, great; however it may be worth investigating a warranty exchange, as that adapter has not always been reliable for others.